# "aptitude update" as cronjob, customize the cron-mail-output

Tags: 11.10, package-management, scripts, aptitude, cron

I have set up `aptitude update` as cronjob for root and sending the mail to my normal user account.

What I want to have now, is that all the output of aptitude is ommited and instead only a summarization of all packages that are new or could be updgraded. Also in case of errors, there should be a list of errorous repos/ppa and the corresponding errormessage.

Is there a way to do such a cronjob, and where can I find informations about scripting such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could think of the following commands:

```
sudo aptitude update >/dev/null 2>update-errors
aptitude search ~U >upgradable-packages
aptitude search ~N >new-packages
sudo aptitude forget-new
```

then in the files `update-errors`, `upgradable-packages` and `new-packages` you could find the information you're looking for. Unfortunately the `forget-new` command, needed to not show again as new the same packages, do not seem to work very well.

For information about the search pattern of `aptitude`, install the package `aptitude-doc-en` (or that in your language, if available), then show the page Search term reference (here an [online version](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html))

The setup of the cronjob, given you already have one, is up to you.

Comment: I cant find documentation about the ~U flag, but I assume it finds only the upgradable packages, not the packages that are "new" in the repos. What is the flag for new packages? If I had this information I think I would be able to setup the rest.

Comment: @NobbZ: see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to get it running as soon as I have some time left that is not consumed by my wife...

Comment: Sorry, but that does not work: `zsh: no such user or named directory: U`

Comment: @NobbZ: Put them between quotes: `'~U'`.

Comment: Yes that did it. I hope I will have the necessary time to fit this all together at the weekend...